# Tool tips in visualforce chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I have a VF where I am plotting percentages in bar graphs, but in the tooltip, I want to show the revenue associated with the record. Please note that percentage and revenue are in the same wrapper class so mapping is not really an issue..

```
       <apex:chart height="220" width="600" data="{!revenue1}" background="#FFFFFF">
    <apex:legend position="top" font="10px Helvetica"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Rev_Growth,Rev_Quota" title="Performance ( % )" />
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="Series1">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="0"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries title="Growth,Quota" orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="Series1" yField="Rev_Growth,Rev_Quota" Stacked="False" colorset="#5B9BD5,#92D050" Gutter="75" groupGutter="75">
        <apex:chartTips height="50" width="120" labelField="Series1" valueField="Revenue,Goal"/>
    </apex:barSeries>
   </apex:chart>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can nest an [apex:chartTips](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartTips.htm) tag inside your data series tag. This lets you nominate different fields from your wrapper class as the source for the tooltip via its `labelField` and `valueField` attributes. So you can set the `apex:chartTips` `valueField` to reference your revenue while the series continues uses the percentage field.

**Update**

From the comment thread, it looks like where comma-separated field names are used, the basic form of `apex:chartTips` does not work: the `valueField` attribute only works with a single name. But it is possible to supply the name of a JavaScript function that renders the tooltip via the `rendererFn` attribute instead though documentation is hard to find. By adding such a function and inspecting its parameters in the browser's JavaScript debugger, I found that the below code code worked. (Note my test case is using different naming to your code.)

Test page and render function:

```
<apex:page controller="A">
<apex:chart height="300" width="300" data="{!revenue}">
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="percentage1,percentage2"/>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="label"/>
    <apex:barSeries title="Growth,Quota" orientation="vertical" axis="left"
                xField="label" yField="percentage1,percentage2" Stacked="False"
                colorset="#5B9BD5,#92D050" Gutter="75" groupGutter="75">
        <apex:chartTips height="25" width="150" rendererFn="renderChartTip"/>
    </apex:barSeries>
</apex:chart>
<script>
function renderChartTip(klass, item) {
    var yField = item.yField;
    var amount = item.storeItem.get(yField === 'percentage1' ? 'amount1' : 'amount2');
    this.setTitle('Amount is ' + amount);
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Test controller:

```
public with sharing class A {
    public class Bean {
        public String label {get; set;}
        public Decimal percentage1 {get; set;}
        public Decimal amount1 {get; set;}
        public Decimal percentage2 {get; set;}
        public Decimal amount2 {get; set;}
        Bean(String label, Decimal percentage1, Decimal amount1,
                Decimal percentage2, Decimal amount2) {
            this.label = label;
            this.percentage1 = percentage1;
            this.amount1 = amount1;
            this.percentage2 = percentage2;
            this.amount2 = amount2;
        }
    }
    public Bean[] revenue {
        get {
            if (revenue == null) {
                revenue = new Bean[] {
                        new Bean('First', 50.00, 50000, 33.33, 33333.33),
                        new Bean('Second', 25.00, 25000, 22.22, 22222.22)
                        };
            }
            return revenue;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: chart with tooltip]

Comment: Hi Keith. Thanks for your reply. I did this. I have updated my question with the code that I am using, but the tooltip continues to show the percent value instead of revenue. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Robin Looks like the problem is that the apex:chartTips valueField doesn't support the comma separated field names. If you just have "Revenue" or "Goal" you will see the value. But then the tooltip is only correct for one or the other. So you may have to resort to writing a custom JavaScript rendererFn (mentioned in http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartTips.htm); should only be a few lines but I haven't found any documentation on it describing the parameters and semantics.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. I will try to search on this line and let you know if I can fix this.

Comment: @Robin I've updated the answer with some rendererFn-based code that works for me.

Comment: This was brilliant!! Thanks a lot Keith. This works exactly the way I wanted.. cheers!!