# Clickable charts on visual force, is that possible?

Tags: charts

I just want to know if it's possible using visualforce Charts api to make a chart clickable, I found a very interesting that shows how to display data when hovering on the chart wedges

```
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/displaying-detailed-data-on-clicking-the-visualforce-chart
```

what I want is when I click on the wedges in the pie chart, the corresponding data will be used to  populate a table and the user will be redirected to an another page where he can visualize this table.

is this idea Realizable using visualforce API, or I am just dreaming?

Answer (score -1):

This is very much possible. We can use all JS libs in salesforce. From JS you can call apex (remote action) and make is dynamic.

Here are few examples

http://salesforcequest.blogspot.in/2014/01/interactive-javascript-charting-for.html

https://github.com/mjrforce/DF13_JQuery_Tables

https://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=CRM+Interactive#{"allowChartStacking":true}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know we can do that using javascript chart providers like HighCharts and google API but i want to know if we can achieve the same thing using just visualforce Chart API