# Drilldown/Popup window in chart

Tags: visualforce

A bar chart is displaying certain data from Case object . Each bar is divided into three colour coded areas denoting three field values. 
On clicking each area a popup/drilldown should happening displaying a few more information .

What should be the possible approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what markup you are using to draw your bar chart. Assuming it is an `apex:chart` then you could use this undocumented (and so not guaranteed to remain available in future releases) technique [Displaying detailed data on clicking the visualforce chart](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/displaying-detailed-data-on-clicking-the-visualforce-chart).

But if this is an important feature for you, I would suggest using a charting library that has appropriate documented APIs such as [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events).