# Tootltip to display fields in VF Page

Tags: visualforce

How to display a few value of fields in the VF Tooltip?

My requirement is to display a few values of 4 fields .
I understand that I may have to use `rendererfn` function .
Can anyone give an example?

How to proceed with :

```
function renderChartTip(klass, item) {
     var yField = item.yField;
     var xyz = 
     this.setTitle(  xyz);
}
```

Comment: You are talking about tooltips for an `apex:chart`?

Comment: @KeithC  Yes . My requirement is to display value of 4 other fields apart from the X/Y fields . Is that possible ?

Comment: Here is an example [Displaying detailed data on clicking the visualforce chart](Displaying detailed data on clicking the visualforce chart) that may help. Use your browser's JavaScript debugger to set a breakpoint and check what data is available in the `item` parameter.

Comment: @KeithC -- your link in the above comment is broken (looks like a copy-paste error)

Comment: @cropredy Thanks, should have been [Displaying detailed data on clicking the visualforce chart](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37006/displaying-detailed-data-on-clicking-the-visualforce-chart).