# Grouping in Visualforce Charts

Tags: dynamic-soql, aggregate, visualforce-charting

I have created a visualforce charting barSeries and it renders the results that I want aside from products with values of zero for the month.

The chart is a repeat business report that is meant to show how many quantities were sold during a particular month. Its intended to also show where products were not sold during a month so sales reps will know which products to target to customers.

The two things that this chart doesn't do yet that I would like it to are:

- Group bars by product codes so legend shows product code's bar color.
- show products with values of zero in addition to those with positive
  values.

What do I need to change in my code to achieve this?

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class VFChartVolReportController {

    public VFChartVolReportController() {

    }


public Account acc {get;set;}   

 public VFChartVolReportController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        // Get information about the Account being worked on
           acc = [select Id, Name, CustomerMasterId__c, ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, Status_Flag__c, (select name, Tier_Code__c from Account_GPOs__r) from Account where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];  
           }
// Data class 
public class Data {   
public String name { get; set; }  
public Integer data1 { get; set; }     
public Data(String name, Integer data1) {       
this.name = name;       
this.data1 = data1;

} 
}   

public List<Data> getChartData(){       

List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT COUNT(Id) inv, Product__r.Name, CALENDAR_MONTH(Actual_Ship_Date__c) monthKey, Sum(Quantity__c) quantityCount  from Invoice_History__c  where Account__c=:acc.Id AND (Product__r.Name like '%Filter%' OR Product__r.Name like '%Rapicide%' OR Product__r.Name like '%Intercept%')  AND Actual_Ship_Date__c >= :Date.newInstance(2013,1,1) group by Product__r.Name, CALENDAR_MONTH(Actual_Ship_Date__c) ORDER BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Actual_Ship_Date__c) asc];   
List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();       
for (AggregateResult ar : arList){        
Integer monthInt = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('monthKey'));
String monthName = monthFromInteger(monthInt); 
Integer quantities = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('quantityCount'));   
dataList.add(new Data(monthName, quantities)); 
}   
return dataList; 
}   
// helper method to translate integer month to month string 
public String monthFromInteger(Integer month){ 
String s; 
s = month == 1 ? 'Jan' : s; 
s = month == 2 ? 'Feb' : s; 
s = month == 3 ? 'Mar' : s; 
s = month == 4 ? 'Apr' : s; 
s = month == 5 ? 'May' : s; 
s = month == 6 ? 'Jun' : s; 
s = month == 7 ? 'Jul' : s; 
s = month == 8 ? 'Aug' : s; 
s = month == 9 ? 'Sep' : s; 
s = month == 10 ? 'Oct' : s; 
s = month == 11 ? 'Nov' : s; 
s = month == 12 ? 'Dec' : s;   

return s; 

}   

}
```

Portion of the VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="AccountSnapShot2,VFChartVolReportController" tabStyle="Account" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"> 
<apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
  <td align="left">
        <table width="10" align="left">
        <tr><td align="right"><apex:chart height="240px" width="600" data="{!chartdata}" animate="true">
<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="inv,name">
<apex:chartLabel orientation="vertical"/> </apex:axis>
<apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" steps="5" fields="data1"/>

<apex:barSeries colorsProgressWithinSeries="false" tips="true" gutter="75" axis="left" orientation="vertical" xField="inv,name" yField="data1" stacked="true">
<apex:chartTips valueField="inv,name" height="50" width="120"/>
</apex:barSeries>

<apex:legend position="bottom"/>
</apex:chart>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to be long so please allow me to post another one.

If the data need to be obtained dynamically, then you should look into ["Providing Chart Data via a JavaScript Array"](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_javascript_function.htm) which allows you to get the data via controller and process it before you pass it to chart function.

Create a map in controller.

```
private static Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> data;
```

Assuming you retrieve month name and each product and its quantity from database one by one, put all data into the map. Please note that you will need **sorting** or some modification of the code to show the graph sorted by month.

```
public static Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> getChartData() {
    data = new Map<String, Map<String,Integer>>();
    //use a loop and edit the code below to putData(retrieved month name, retrieved quantity, retrieved product code);
    for (AggregateResult  ar: HERE IS YOUR QUERY ) {
            data.putData(monthFromInteger(monthInt), Integer.valueOf(ar.get('quantityCount')), yourProductName);
    }
    return data;
}

private static void putData(String name, Integer quantity, String productCode){
    Map<String,Integer> productGroup = new Map<String,Integer>();
    if (data.containsKey(name)){
        productGroup = data.get(name);
    }
    productGroup.put(productCode, quantity);
    data.put(name, productGroup);
}
```

Once you have your data in a map, you can pass the values to javascript array using the method below.

```
<script>
    // Build the chart data array in JavaScript
    var data = new Array();
</script>

<apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="monthList">
<script type="text/javascript">
var product = {};
</script>
<apex:repeat value="{!data[monthList]}" var="productList">
    {!monthList} {!productList} {!data[monthList][productList]}<br/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        product['{!productList}'] = {!data[monthList][productList]};
        product['name'] = '{!monthList}';
    </script>
</apex:repeat>
<script type="text/javascript">
data.push(product);
</script>
</apex:repeat>
```

And pass the array to apex chart.

```
<apex:chart data="data" height="400" width="500">
    <apex:legend position="left"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" title="title" grid="true"
        fields="{!yfield}" dashSize="2">
        <apex:chartLabel />
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" 
        xField="name" yField="{!yfield}" title="{!title}"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I guess the part I don't understand is how to create that loop to populate the data because what you put in the answer above is static data: "//use a loop and edit the code below to putData(retrieved month name, retrieved quantity, retrieved product code);
    putData('Jan', 50, 'data1');
    putData('Jan', 20, 'data2');
    putData('Jan', 15, 'data3');
    putData('Feb', 30, 'data1');
    putData('Feb', 25, 'data2');
    putData('Feb', 20, 'data3');"

Comment: You can change that part to [SOQL for loop](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm). I edited my post.

Comment: So your code above is in addition to the code i have already written or do i have to get rid of certain lines? I tried integrating it with my code and it keeps telling me that the variable arList doesn't exist

Comment: @lw29 - I helped NewbieDeveloper27 through the controller compile, but when she runs the VF page she gets:

Error is in expression '{!data[monthList][productList]}' in component <apex:repeat> in page

and 

Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Number

Can you check your VF code example and provide guidance to proceed?

Comment: Would adding TEXT () help?

Comment: That will not work...I am going to need to pass through the month name list somehow because the {!data} feature will only pass in the number the months are associated with. I need to pass in the monthFromInteger aspect in the class but can't quite figure that out.

Comment: Do you get the object data correctly but can't build a graph? If you are still having any problems you might need to provide some codes.

Comment: I pasted my current code on Pastbin: http://pastebin.com/tsCt9j0i. I get the error: Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Number
Error is in expression '{!data[monthList][productList]}' in component <apex:repeat> in page account_snap_shot     ....due to the months being created as integers and then passing them through the monthFromInteger variable

Comment: Could you log the data map in the controller and check that months are string and have a value?

Answer (score 1):

**For static grouped bar chart:**

Do the product codes need to be obtained dynamically from database? If not you can create a grouped bar chart like [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm).

Your data class would look like below.

```
public class Data {   
   public String name { get; set; }  
   public Integer data1 { get; set; }   
   public Integer data2 { get; set; }  
   //add more data   
   public Data(String name, Integer data1, Integer data2, ...) {       
      this.name = name;       
      this.data1 = data1; //MF01-0013
      this.data2 = data2; //MF01-0059
      //add more data
   } 
}
```

And this would be your chart's code.

```
<apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" 
xField="name" yField="data1,data2,..." title="MF01-0013,MF01-0059,..." />
```

If you want to change the chart's tooltips, please refer to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/tool-tips-in-visualforce-chart).

Comment: There are hundreds of product codes and they need to be obtained dynamically from the database. So creating a static grouped bar chart wouldn't work out. The graph is going to change depending on which account it is in.

Comment: Please see my another answer.