# Visual force Grouped Bar charts

Tags: visualforce, charts

I need to develop grouped bar chart in visualforce. I referred documentation but is having example where grouping is done with fixed number of records.

What chart will have:

**X-axes** : Account records grouped by created date. **Each date will have separate bars for each account created on that day. On hover of bars i want account name to be displayed.**

**Y-axes:** Total of opportunity amount. I created 1 roll-up summary field for that.

Now each created date will have different numbers of account and this is the place where i am getting stuck. Salesforce doc is having example with static data set.

Appreciate if anybody help em to get this done. I also referred this link [Grouping in Visualforce Charts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45142/grouping-in-visualforce-charts)  but no luck.

**For example/reference I want chart like this:**
[image]

VF Page:

Comment: what have you done? Where are you stuck? What is the problem?

Comment: legend shows Product Code but question refers to Accounts. ??

Comment: This given picture is only for example.

Chart will have:

X-axes : Account records grouped by created date. Each date will have separate bars for each account created on that day. On hover of bars i want account name to be displayed.

Y-axes: Total of opportunity amount. I created 1 roll-up summary field for that.

Somehow i am good with chart generated but nit sure if this is right way to code. Plus in this the issue that onhover Account name is not displayed. How to do that?. I used <apex:chartTips> but no positive output.

Below in the next comment is the code i am having:

Comment: I am not able to add code. How can i do that? it showing too long text message.