# rendererFn in Visualforce ChartTip

Tags: visualforce

Is there any documentation available for the rendererFn in VF ChartTip??
Apart from the official one , which doesnot really explain much ,

can anybody who has worked extensively on it explain a with a basic JS function how it works and what are it's limitations ?

Can we change the colour/shape of the tooltip based on certain parameters?

Comment: You might be able to find something in the underlying JavaScript library documentation which I think is http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/. I used the JavaScript debugger to find what I needed for this [Tool tips in visualforce chart](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/tool-tips-in-visualforce-chart/33170#33170) answer - you could do the same to see what data is available.