# Show Percentage on wedges of pie chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts, visualforce-charting

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection >  

   <apex:chart height="250" width="350"  data="{!PieData}" resizable="true">
     <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" />
     <apex:legend position="bottom"/>
   </apex:chart>    

</apex:pageBlockSection>    




  public class MyController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<WrapperClass> getPieData() {
     List<WrapperClass> data = new List<WrapperClass>();

     data.add(new WrapperClass('Total Count',84));
     data.add(new WrapperClass('Express',82));   
     data.add(new CASRWrapperClasseport('Normal',20));      

     return data;
    }
  }


   public class WrapperClass{
      public string name {get;set;}
      public integer data {get;set;}

      public WrapperClass(String namevalue, Integer datavalue) {
         this.name = namevalue;
         this.data = datavalue;

      }

   }
```

**Current Output is similar to this** . I get the percentage when i hover on each wedge.

[image]

**I am trying to get similar to this** . The percentage should be on wedge, and the legend will categorize what each color represents.

[image]

Comment: You have to use `rendererFn` that will give you JS, which you can use to customize your pie chart. Something similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/tool-tips-in-visualforce-chart/33170#33170

Comment: I copied and pasted exact code in the salesforce documentation as shown here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm The output as shown in this example doesn't have month names on the wedges. However the output i get has month names on the wedges. This example doesn't uses rendererFn property. I am wondering why i see month names and the example shown does'nt?